# fullscreen menu height issue because address bar (mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I would like to make a fullscreen menu in mobile, but the address bar always makes it look bad.

My menu has 4 equal height items and they are `fixed`  positioned.
The problem is, when the user scroll the page on mobile, there will be a little gap at the bottom of the page, and the user can see a page behind the navigation. Is there a good solution to fix this issue?

Here is the HTML file:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item1</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item2</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item3</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item4</a></div>
</nav>
```

and the style.css :

```
.menu-item{
  position: fixed;
  width:100vw;
  height:25vh;
  left:0;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(1){
  top:0;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(2){
  top:25vh;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(3){
  top:50vh;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(4){
  top:75vh;
}
```

As you can see I'm using `vh` units for the `height` and `top` attribute.

In chrome it is working good, but on iPhone safari and chrome (latest both) it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fixing each element like that, why not just fix the parent and make each child 25%:

```css
nav {
  /* covers the whole screen so you shouldn't get a gap*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  min-height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item1</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item2</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item3</a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item4</a></div>
</nav>
```